# Multi-threading / Parallel Processing

Tags: python, multithreading

I have few hundreds of input files that I need to pass to a function to calculate some numbers, and write them to an output file. The function does not return any value. So, each function call is independent.

Instead of calling the function serially, I tried multiprocessing, and the performance (execution time)  is not much better. Any suggestions on improving the performance is valuable. Is even multiprocessing the way to go for this problem?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
NumProcess = 4

def Analysis(InputFile):
    #do some calcs
    #Write results to output file
    #return nothing

FileList = ['InputFile1.csv','InputFile2.csv','InputFile3.csv',....]
pool = mp.Pool(processes=NumProcess)
temp = [pool.apply_async(Analysis, args=(File) for File in FileList]
output = [p.get() for p in temp]
pool.close()
```

Comment: yes - multiprocessing is the right, simplest approach there. Maybe your bottleneck is somewhere else. If you have at least two cpu cores this should be better.

Comment: There is an opening parentheresis too much in this listing, though

Comment: Is your algorithm CPU-bound or I/O bound?  If it's I/O bound, then spawning multiple threads/processes won't make it any faster, and might make it slower if it causes your hard drive's heads to have to seek back and forth a lot more than they would in the single-thread/single-process case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the mutiprocssing call works at all? There is an error on this line - as you don't pass the File argument as a tuple at all.

Corrected version (note the trailing comma to ensure args is a tuple):

```
temp = [pool.apply_async(Analysis, args=(File,)) for File in FileList]
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Sorry, missed the the trailing comma and the bracket when I was editing the post. Since the function calls are independent, I thought there should be a more efficient way to parallel process the files.

Comment: There is an easier way - but it is not more efficient. In Python 3 yu can use concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor - but if this did not speed you up, so won't conucurrent.futures.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I can loop over all the input files in a way to let each available processor run one of the input files parallely? For example - Processor1 - Analysis(InputFile1); Processor2 - Analysis(InputFile2),....

Comment: Is it not doing 1 file at a time across multiple processors because of  [pool.apply_async(Analysis, args=(File) for File in FileList]?

Comment: No - what would be the purpose of having  a pool with ths method then? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

Comment: Because of the "for" loop, my understanding was, the code takes 1 file at a time and parallel processes it, before moving on to the second file.

Comment: No,, ti makes on call to `apply_async` before making the next call - but this function is the one that offloads the parametr to be executed in an external process and returns immediately)